# Finding out which module a function belongs to

Tags: haskell, ghci

In ghci (haskell) is there a command which will tell me which module (out of the loaded modules) a function belongs to. e.g. if the function is called whichMod, then it would work as follows :

```
Prelude>whichMod take
Prelude
Prelude>whichMod sort
Data.List
```

Comment: For functions not loaded in the current session, thre's always [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=sort). You may build a hoogle client and add it to ghci. The [GOA](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/GHCi#GHCi_on_Acid) package does it for you.

Comment: @n.m. Hmm that looks very interesting. Tried to install GOA but then I got the dreaded cabal message "cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:". Maybe I'll come back to this when I am a bit more experienced with cabal! Thanks

Comment: I dunno, I use gentoo and its haskell overlay. I just say `emerge goa`. The try to publish versions that work together.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks. I managed to get both cabal-dev and virthualenv working, but when trying to build GOA I was getting some `Not in scope: localeEncoding` due to `System/Process/Internals.hs`. A problem for another day...:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the `:i` command (short for `:info`).

```
Prelude> :i take
take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]   -- Defined in GHC.List
Prelude> :i sort

Top level: Not in scope: `sort'
Prelude> :m +Data.List
Prelude Data.List> :i sort
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]     -- Defined in Data.List
```

As you suggest, it only works if the function is in a currently loaded module.

Note that you are told which module the function is originally defined in. e.g. `take` is defined in `GHC.List` (at least in my copy of ghc), but re-exported from the prelude. You are not told which module(s) you imported it from.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, exists that function:

```
Prelude> :! hoogle sort
Data.List sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
Data.List sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
Data.ByteString sort :: ByteString -> ByteString
Data.ByteString.Char8 sort :: ByteString -> ByteString
Data.Sequence sort :: Ord a => Seq a -> Seq a
package sort-by-pinyin
Data.Sequence sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> Seq a -> Seq a
GHC.Exts sortWith :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
package sorty
package cabal-sort
package external-sort
Data.Graph.Inductive.Internal.Heap heapsort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
package heapsort
package natural-sort
package NaturalSort
Data.Graph topSort :: Graph -> [Vertex]
Data.Graph.Inductive.Query.DFS topsort :: Graph gr => gr a b -> [Node]
Data.Graph.Inductive.Query.DFS topsort' :: Graph gr => gr a b -> [a]
Data.Sequence unstableSort :: Ord a => Seq a -> Seq a
Data.Sequence unstableSortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> Seq a -> Seq a
Prelude> _
```

you can define a alias into your *"~/.ghci"* configuration file

```
:def hoogle \str -> return $ ":! hoogle \"" ++ str ++ "\""
```

then, you can write

```
Prelude> :hoogle sort
Data.List sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
Data.List sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
Data.ByteString sort :: ByteString -> ByteString
Data.ByteString.Char8 sort :: ByteString -> ByteString
Data.Sequence sort :: Ord a => Seq a -> Seq a
package sort-by-pinyin
Data.Sequence sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> Seq a -> Seq a
GHC.Exts sortWith :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
package sorty
package cabal-sort
package external-sort
Data.Graph.Inductive.Internal.Heap heapsort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
package heapsort
package natural-sort
package NaturalSort
Data.Graph topSort :: Graph -> [Vertex]
Data.Graph.Inductive.Query.DFS topsort :: Graph gr => gr a b -> [Node]
Data.Graph.Inductive.Query.DFS topsort' :: Graph gr => gr a b -> [a]
Data.Sequence unstableSort :: Ord a => Seq a -> Seq a
Data.Sequence unstableSortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> Seq a -> Seq a
Prelude> _
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really useful. I had heard of hoogle before, but now I know how to use it!:)

Comment: I'm happy to return some of the aid received ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
Prelude> :info take
take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]   -- Defined in `GHC.List'
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure which answer came first but gave a +1 for this:)