# Get a list of what is exported by a module

Tags: haskell

Similar question ([Is there a way to see the list of functions in a module, in GHCI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698942/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-list-of-functions-in-a-module-in-ghci)), though not the result that I seek.

Is there a way to get a list of what is exported by a module?

Of course in GHCi you can import it then type `Some.Module.`, hit tab for auto-completion and it will show what I seek. But I want to capture that stuff. Roughly speaking, `String -> [String]`.

*Purpose?* Suppose that I have a source file with a naked `import Some.Module`. Question: What belongs to `Some.Module` in that file? A simple way would be to output the list of what the module exports, feed that to `grep` and return the contenders, without the need to load that source file in GHCi (might be complicated or not possible). And everything becomes a lot clearer.

If there's a smarter approach to that, I'm listening. [I heard of solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722203/finding-out-which-module-a-function-belongs-to) involving `GOA` and `lambdabot`. No idea if applicable or how to make use of this.

Comment: `-ddump-minimal-imports` will tell you what things from `Some.Module` are used in a file, though if the same thing is imported twice, it might not appear in the import list associated with `Some.Module`. I think this fulfills your purpose, but it does not answer your question.

Comment: Didn't know this one. A very useful compiler option. Something to add to my arsenal for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A particularly simple way for interactive use is `:browse`. Load up a ghci that has access to the appropriate package, then

```
> :browse Some.Module
class Some.Module.Foo a where
  Some.Module.foo :: a -> a
  {-# MINIMAL foo #-}
Some.Module.bar :: Int
```

All the qualification can get a bit much, especially if there are many functions that operate on types defined in the same module. To reduce the clutter, you can bring `Some.Module` into scope first:

```
> :m + Some.Module
> :browse Some.Module
class Foo a where
  foo :: a -> a
  {-# MINIMAL foo #-}
bar :: Int
```

Comment: I am aware of `:browse`, it was mentioned in the post that I referred to, and it does not do what I need, which is: i) list only what it exports and nothing else; ii) allow me to take that output somewhere else (non-interactive).

Comment: @p_barill Interesting. What does `:browse` list that isn't exported? As for taking it somewhere non-interactive, `echo :browse Some.Module | ghci` is a perfectly suitable start to a pipeline that you can append to for whatever non-interactive processing you want.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Never thought about piping to an interpreter like this! I was looking only for the name of functions without type signatures and classes, but I see that an astute regex should grab just what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As @HTNW mentioned in a comment, if you can run `ghc` on your actual file, you can use `-ddump-minimal-imports`.  Otherwise, if you want to actually get the list of exports from another module, assuming that you're using GHC, the easiest way to do this is probably to look at the `.hi` [interface files](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/commentary/compiler/iface-files).  `ghc` has some built-in support for printing human-readable representations of interface files once you know the path to one, but as the wiki page notes "This textual format is not particularly designed for machine parsing".  You can also access the information you might want via the GHC API.  A small example of doing something like that follows.

We start with a bunch of random imports for doing IO & from the GHC api:

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import System.IO
import System.Environment

import GHC
import GHC.Paths (libdir)
import DynFlags
import Outputable
import Name
import Pretty (Mode(..))
```

With that bureaucracy out of the way, `main` starts by firing up the GHC Monad:

```
main :: IO ()
main = defaultErrorHandler defaultFatalMessager defaultFlushOut $ do
  runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
```

We're not actually generating any code so we can set `hscTarget = HscNothing` during the `DynFlags` setup boilerplate:

```
    dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
    let dflags' = dflags { hscTarget = HscNothing }
    setSessionDynFlags dflags'
```

With that out of the way we can find the module we want from the package database (using the first command-line argument as the name):

```
    mn <- head <$> (liftIO $ getArgs)
    m <- lookupModule (mkModuleName mn) Nothing
```

We can use `getModuleInfo` to get a module info structure:

```
    mmi <- getModuleInfo m
    case mmi of
      Nothing -> liftIO $ putStrLn "Could not find module interface"
```

If we did find the interface, everything we need for this is in the `modInfoExports`.  If we needed more, we could also get the actual `ModIface`:

```
      Just mi -> mapM_ (printExport dflags') (modInfoExports mi)
```

Actually printing out an exported is a bit tedious, as it requires working with `Name`s; a simple example `printExport` might just use the pretty-printing functions, but these are more intended for printing human-readable output than machine-readable:

```
printExport :: DynFlags -> Name -> Ghc ()
printExport dflags n =
  liftIO $ printSDocLn PageMode dflags stdout (defaultUserStyle dflags)
         $ pprNameUnqualified n
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing something so detailed. Is this something that can be used? If so, what do I feed it? I get `error: Variable not in scope: s :: HscEnv`. I'll take this as the definitive proof that what I seek can be done in theory but not in practice (if I wanted to learn those things, no idea how I would get that).

Comment: Woops, sorry, something slightly stale got posted! I just edited to fix it.  Note that this is doing basically the same thing as the :browse trick suggested above, except from within Haskell (faster & no need to pipe/parse data) and possibly more stable (GHCi's output format changes, but then again so does the GHC API---although I believe most of the parts used here are relatively stable).